# How is this statistical index called?

Tags: statistics, median, percentile, quantile

I need to calculate an index that is to be derived like this:

If we have some data: `850 700 500 480 300 100 50`, we first sort it from the large to small:

```
850
700
500
480
300
100
50
```

Then calculate the sum: 2980.

Then we take a given number of percents, for example, 50% and get a 50% of the sum:1490. Then we go down the data, calculating the sum for the given row plus the sum of all the rows prior:

```
850    850
700    1550
500    2050
480    2530
300    2830
100    2930
50     2980
```

Once the sum in the second row equals or exceed the 50% of the total sum = 5050 we take the corresponding number from the first row: 700. So that number is the aswer.

What is that number called? I need to know to find an appropriate excel function to calculate it.

Comment: Your procedure, for $50\%$, is a greedy algorithm that does successfully generate a set of the smallest size that contains a majority of the total. It doesn't have to have a name for you to be able to make an excel function for it.

Comment: For this I would recommend writing a VBA Excel macro

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee I have a feeling a function for this already exists, it looks like some common statistical index to me. I just don't know its name.

Comment: This question had been better asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/   I think you can answer your question yourself, after reading https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137931/when-would-we-use-tantiles-and-the-medial-rather-than-quantiles-and-the-median

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen So it's called tantile? Thank you for the link. It's weird how I can hardly google anythin for that word. It must have a very rare use.

Answer (score 1):

Still no idea how it's called, but here's how I implemented the search for it in vba:

```
Function getSecondAverage(tempArray() As Variant)
    Dim globals As Object
    Set globals = getGlobalVariables()

    Dim arr As Object
    Set arr = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    Dim elements_sum As Double
    elements_sum = 0
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
        arr.Add tempArray(i)

        elements_sum = elements_sum + tempArray(i)
    Next

    arr.Sort
    arr.Reverse

    Dim percentile_value As Double
    percentile_value = _
        globals("DEBT_DIVIDE_PERCENTILE_PERCENT") * elements_sum

    Dim accumulated_sum As Double
    accumulated_sum = 0

    Dim element As Variant
    For Each element In arr
        accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + element

        If accumulated_sum >= percentile_value Then
            getSecondAverage = element
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```